# Splunk - Specify drill down search

Tags: splunk, sideviewutils

I'm relatively new to Splunk and am creating a new view to display the average timings of certain events over the past 5 mins. I've created a macro search to carry out the search which takes two parameters (transaction name and duration to search), so in my first panel this is EVENT_*_LOGIN and -5m. The view currently displays a simple table of results per distinct event name.

What I would like to do is when a user clicks on a particular row it will drill down to timeline view of all events for that transaction over the past 4 hours. Is there a way to specify the information a click or drill down displays?

Apologies if this vague, please message me if more info. needed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use [**SideView Utils**](http://sideviewapps.com/apps/sideview-utils/) and leverage their `Redirector` or `Search` module to custom fill the search query based upon what the user clicks.

#### Opens Custom Search in Popup based upon clicked Chart

```xml
<module name="FlashChart">
    <param name="width">100%</param>
    <module name="Redirector">
        <param name="popup">True</param>
        <param name="url">flashtimeline</param>
        <param name="arg.q">search MyField="$click.value$" eventtype="#$click.name2$" hoursago=4</param>
    </module>
</module>
```

#### Opens Custom Search in Popup based upon clicked Table element

```xml
<module name="SimpleResultsTable">
    <param name="drilldown">all</param> 
    <module name="Redirector">
        <param name="popup">True</param>
        <param name="url">flashtimeline</param>
        <param name="arg.q">search MyField="$click.value$" eventtype="#$click.name2$" hoursago=4</param>
    </module>
</module>
```

You can access the documentation for `Search`/`Redirector` using your Splunk Web install:

```
    http://[splunk_web]/en-US/modules#Splunk.Module.Redirector
    http://[splunk_web]/en-US/modules#Splunk.Module.Search
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Splunk version 5 they now support dynamic drilldown.  Check the docs [here](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Viz/Dynamicdrilldownindashboardsandforms) to see if that does what you need.